# ini_set() scope of effect?

Tags: php, php-ini

I've had `index.php` and several files which cascading include,something like this.

```
index.php -> controller.php -> model.php -> view.php
```

In `model.php` I have a function using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

When will the [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set) change of the setting expire?

After executed `index.php`? Or `view.php`? Or the function in `model.php`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`ini_set()` is **global** for everything that happens in the script (not just the current file: the whole thread of execution that is occurring), for this entire one request; it doesn't matter whence you invoke it, it will always affect the **global** settings for this script. The effect will expire when your script terminates - e.g. through `exit`, `die`, or running off the end of `index.php`.

It will not affect any other scripts running simultaneously (those need to call `ini_set` themselves), and it will not persist into later requests (if you need persistent settings, you need to edit `php.ini`).

Note that the [documentation says the same thing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

---

Edit: Since it is apparently unclear: the value you change using `ini_set` will be valid for the whole script onwards. It doesn't matter where the execution currently is (in what file, in what class, in what function); the setting will be the same, everywhere. It will remain so until you change it again, or until the whole script terminates. (not the current file, not the current function; the whole script)

Comment: I've already read the document but I wonder will it effect in function scope(like variable) or the entire script after using this function.I'm not sure what their "script" means.

Comment: @thReality: Did you read my answer? Quote: "it doesn't matter whence you invoke it, it will always affect the global settings for this script" - in other words, completely regardless of function scope.

Comment: "it doesn't matter whence you invoke it"
it matters when you invoke it, "ini_set will be valid for the whole script onwards.";

Comment: @csstd: And? "whence" != "when". "Whence", adj. 1. From which place. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whence

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @user973810: Link to PHP documentation is not reference enough for you? Sorry, I have nothing more authoritative than that.

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading it correctly, but I find the documentation's wording to be vague. Thanks though.

Comment: It is indeed somewhat vague; I don't have anything better than the documentation (and observation which is completely consistent with it), though.

Comment: "during the script's execution" is not obvious if you aren't sure what is meant by "the script". If I define a class in "myclass.php" I might consider "myclass.php" to be a PHP "script", and if I call ini_set in a function in that class, I might incorrectly guess that the value is restored outside of my "script" function call. So unfortunately by repeating the words "the script" over and over again the answer doesn't become more clear if the person doesn't know that "the script" is referring to the whole thread of execution that is occurring.

Comment: I wonder what the execution scope when this isn't called at the top of the script?

Comment: @KolobCanyon: The notion of scope doesn't quite apply here, this is not a variable. Doesn't matter where you call this: from that point, in this current running script, the new value applies everywhere. (Is "global" unclear?)

Comment: @Piskvor First of all, variables are not the only entities that have scope in Php - functions for one have a scope; `ini_set() is a function and therefore has scope... it absolutely applies here. The question, which you unkindly did not answer, was if Php would still take the `ini_set()` into effect even if it was the last instruction in the script and apply that to the commands above it, which now I'm pretty sure php takes everything one line at a time... so the answer to my question is no.

Comment: @Kolob Canyon: If "the value you change using ini_set will be valid for the whole script onwards" in the answer and variations in the comments are not clear enough or kind enough for you, then I have no better way to explain this. I suggest that you try someone else to pester: I've explained it to the best of my ability, there is nothing more that I could do.

Comment: So if you set X memory_limit using ini_set on a script and you run it twice simultaneously, does that mean the scripts will allocate 2X memory?